# Надо ли коммитить оба requirements.in и requirements.txt в репозиторий?

Tags: python, git, зависимости, requirements.txt

Читаю про `pip-compile` и не понимаю, почему многие репозитории содержат оба файла `requirements.txt` и `requirements.in`. Разве не лучше иметь только `requirements.in` и в инструкции по установке указывать, что надо сделать `requirements.txt` через `pip-compile`?

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю суть, requirements.txt содержит точные версии библиотек, и знание точных версий позволяет воссоздать точно такое же окружение, которое было у автора репозитория

Comment: @andreymal точные версии можно указать и в `requirements.in` (если они важны). Основной плюс `pip-compile`, как я понимаю, в том, что ты указываешь только непосредственно зависимости твоего проекта, в то время как голый `requirements.txt` содержит зависимости зависимостей. Но если при этом ты коммитишь и `requirements.txt`, то тебе надо следить за обновлением зависимостей там. Например, у тебя есть `numpy` в `requirements.in`, `pip-compile` делает из него `numpy==0.42` в `requirements.txt`. И теперь при обновлении `numpy` до `0.43` тебе надо обновлять самому `requirements.txt`, если он в репе.

Comment: Поэтому я вместо pip-compile использую poetry, который обновляет всё сам)

Comment: Очевидно потому, что люди по своей природе ленивы. Не хотят читать документацию и делать всё более точно. Так что *.txt не нужен, если он генерируется.